# JSON.Net Schema Error Messages

Tags: .net, validation, json.net

I'm using JSON.Net Schema and I'm wondering if there is a way to customize the error messages returned from the IsValid function.

The error message being returned is:

```
"Message": "Float 1.2 exceeds maximum value of 1. Path 'fields.Indirect_Cost_Rate', line 4, position 40."
```

I'd like the error message to say:

```
"Message": "Indirect_Cost_Rate must be a number between 0 and 1 with a maximum of 4 decimal places. Path 'fields.Indirect_Cost_Rate', line 4, position 40."
```

With .Net I can add this to the property:

```
<Range(0, 1, ErrorMessage:="Indirect_Cost_Rate must be a number between 0 and 1 with a maximum of 4 decimal places.")>
```

Thanks, AD